# Sorry.Google.com Captcha workaround needed for a .NET WPF C# 4.0 Application

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, captcha

My application uses Google to search for information and retrieves it. After a few searches, I get the dreaded Sorry.Google.com message and asking me to verify that I am not a bot and then my application crashes. I need the code to actually present the captcha page as a popup or WPF browser window when I am presented with it so that it can be entered and the application will then proceed on doing what it was doing. I am using HTTPWebRequest to fetch the search engine page. I can imagine the code would see that Google was first serving the captcha page so then it would halt activity instead of crashing, allow someone to enter the captcha and then proceed normally fetching the information. Another workaround would be to avoid crashing altogether but I have not been able to prevent that either. I am most interested in the solving the captcha issue as I think that would be the best solution. Any code for this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you're using a program to search Google then having a human user to solve the anti-program CAPTCHA on its behalf?

Comment: Yes, for example if the Google captcha comes up, the human would have to solve the captcha for it to continue with the search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you did manage to do this, that's a violation of the Google TOS and will likely get you and your users banned. If you want to search google in some automated way, consider Google Custom Search which provides an actual API for you to query against.

http://www.google.com/cse/

Comment: However, that custom search is for websites and blogs and not applications